# Gerenciamento de Telas Python + tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou criando um sistema com algumas telas,  Toda vez que clico no botão para chamar a tela ela cria uma nova instancia da mesma tela, então se o usuário ficar clicando no mesmo botão serão criadas várias novas telas iguais. Quero que ao abrir uma tela só possa abrir outra da mesma se a primeira for fechada.

Segue Código:

```
from tkinter import *
import time



#MENU PRINCIPAL DO SISTEMA
janelamenu = Tk()

def janela_criar_usuario():
    janelacriarusuario = Tk()

    janelacriarusuario.geometry("600x600+250+50")
    #janelacriarusuario.mainloop()

def janela_edit_usuario():
    janelaeditusuario = Tk()

    janelaeditusuario.geometry("600x600+250+50")
    janelaeditusuario.mainloop()


menu_bt_criar = Button(janelamenu, text='Criar Usuario',command=janela_criar_usuario)
menu_bt_edituser = Button(janelamenu, text='Editar Usuario',command=janela_edit_usuario)
menu_bt_criar.place(x=30,y=100)
menu_bt_edituser.place(x=30,y=130)

janelamenu.geometry("200x600+50+50")
janelamenu.title("Menu Principal")
janelamenu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que eu encontrei foi abrir uma janela principal com o menu do sistema exibindo os dois botões com as opções criar e editar usuário. Quando um dos botões for pressionado a janela principal é destruída e uma nova janela com o mesmo nome é criada com novos elementos e um botão de voltar para o menu principal. Desta forma o usuário não conseguirá abrir mais de uma janela ao mesmo tempo.

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
label = Label(janela, text='Menu Principal')
label.pack()


def criar_usuario():
    global janela
    janela.destroy()
    janela = Tk() 
    label = Label(janela, text='Criar Usuario')
    label.pack()
    janela.geometry("600x600+250+50")
    menu_bt = Button(janela, text='Voltar/Menur',command=menu)
    menu_bt.pack()


def editar_usuario():
    global janela
    janela.destroy()
    janela = Tk() 
    label = Label(janela, text='Editar Usuario')
    label.pack()
    janela.geometry("600x600+250+50")
    menu_bt = Button(janela, text='Voltar/Menur',command=menu)
    menu_bt.pack()


def menu():
    global janela
    janela.destroy()
    janela = Tk()

    label = Label(janela, text='Menu Principal')
    label.pack()

    menu_bt_criar = Button(janela, text='Criar Usuario',command=criar_usuario)
    menu_bt_edituser = Button(janela, text='Editar Usuario',command=editar_usuario)

    menu_bt_criar.place(x=30,y=100)
    menu_bt_edituser.place(x=30,y=130)

    janela.geometry("600x600+250+50")
    janela.title("Menu Principal")

    janela.mainloop()


menu_bt_criar = Button(janela, text='Criar Usuario',command=criar_usuario)
menu_bt_edituser = Button(janela, text='Editar Usuario',command=editar_usuario)

menu_bt_criar.place(x=30,y=100)
menu_bt_edituser.place(x=30,y=130)

janela.geometry("600x600+250+50")
janela.title("Menu Principal")

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ótima solução! Consegui solucionar meu problema, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz que a minha resposta tenha te ajudado. Abraço e até a próxima!